# Allowing subclasses to designate which method they want to decorate with in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, subclassing, python-decorators

I'm DRY'ing up some code that had a class code copy and pasted around. I've made the code into subclasses the implement the desired elements that are different, but one of the remnants of the code was that a different decorator specific to each class was called for a commonly named method.

In this example, it's the `foo` method. `@some_decorator_function` used to be imported from another namespace for each class. Now that the decorator is only called once from the parent class, it does not know what decorator to use as the subclass needs to pick it.

Is there a way to delegate the function to decorate with to a subclass?

What I had in mind (and raises the `NotImplementedError` immediately because X is evaluated):

```
class X:

  def some_decorator_function():
    raise NotImplementedError

  @some_decorator_function()
  def foo(self):
    return "Yo!"


def concrete_function(func):
  pass

class Y(X):
  def some_decorator_function():
    concrete_function

Y().foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to explicitly apply the right decorator in Y:

```
class X:
    def foo(self):
        return "Yo!"

def concrete_function(func):
    pass

class Y(X):
    foo = concrete_function(X.foo)

Y().foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the decorator to a more generic pattern.

```
def class_defined_decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return args[0]._decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Base(object):
    def _decorator(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError
    @class_defined_decorator
    def foo(self):
        pass

class Child(Base):
    def _decorator(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do decorator behavior
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

You could get fancier by making the decorator return a descriptor if you have to support decorating static, class, and instance methods with the same decorator.